# I have got data from database in variable buffer and I want that data to be displayed in listview

Tags: android, sqlite

I have got data from database in variable buffer and I want that data to be displayed in `ListView`

This is my adaper

```
private void setAdapterData() {

    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);

            for (students stud : CustomListViewValuesArr) {
                db.insertContact(stud.getrollno(), stud.getfirst(), stud.getsecond(), stud.getper());


            }

            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");

            ArrayList<students> stu = db.getAllCotacts();
            res = getResources();

            adapter = new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, stu, res);
            studentlist.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
        }
```

Comment: I think you missed posting the actual code for your `CustomAdapter`

Comment: do not use any custom `CustomAdapter` extending `BaseAdapter` / `ArrayAdapter`, use `[Simple]CursorAdapter` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am done,

send intent from this activity to another activity  using Cursor

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);

```
                    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                        showMessage("No records found");
                        return;
                    }

                //   convert array list to string

                List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();

                    while (c.moveToNext())
                        {

                            buffer.add("" + c.getString(1)+ " "+ c.getString(2));

                        }

                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, viewdetails.class);
                            intent.putStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, (ArrayList<String>) buffer);
                            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

In another list activity

```
    Intent intent=getIntent();

    ArrayList<String> buffer = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    ListView lListView = new ListView(this);
    lListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.content);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,buffer);

    lListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```